# no arguments that correspond to the mandatory formal parameter item1 have been specified

Tags: c#

I've this object:

```
public class RankingAll
{
   public Tuple<List<Ranking>, List<RankingLegend>> Ranking { get; set; } 
}
```

I've declared this:

```
RankingAll rankingAll = new RankingAll();
rankingAll.Ranking = new Tuple<List<Ranking>, List<RankingLegend>>();
```

but I get a compiler error on the last line

> no arguments that correspond to the mandatory formal parameter item1 have been specified

what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tuples are immutable, so cannot be changed after construction. You can't set `Item1` or `Item2` after this point, so the only way to get values into it are at construction. This is enforced by a constructor signature that *requires* the values.

You need to supply values to the constructor, or use the handy helper method:

```
Tuple.Create(new List<Ranking>(), new List<RankingLegend>())
```

Given that a Tuple is immutable, placing mutable structures within it is, IMO, somewhat questionable.

Answer (score 0):

Your tuple requires two items (A List and a List) to be passed into the constructor. You can't construct a tuple without the members of the tuple being provided.

Comment: I just need to create the tuple

Comment: You can’t just create a tuple without items in the tuple (passed into the constructor)